# MS-Exchange contacts are not synching even though mail and calendar syncs fine

Tags: contacts, sync, exchange, active-sync

For a while now my **contacts** quit synching on Android with an Exchange 2010 server. Calendar and Mail syncing still works, both directions. This problem is described elsewhere ( e.g. [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/troubleshoot-contacts-and-calendar-sync-between-android-and-exchange/) ) and I tried all the proposed fixes:

- Click "sync now" in accounts, deactivate contacts, click again, re-activate contacts, click again
- Check that the account is really a "Microsoft Exchange" (i.e. active sync) account, not IMAP, etc
- Create a new dummy contact on phone or Outlook and sync again...
- Use the Dev Tools Sync Tester on Android (always returned empty `stats=[]`, no errors...) :-(

Versions:

- Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 14.3.158.4001
- Android 4.3 (Cyanogen 10.2 on Motorola Defy+)

Comment: Hi! Please make sure that only the question is included in the question, then answer your own question with what turned out to be the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how to properly use the Q/A style storytelling over here :) Will do!

Comment: I must wait 8 h because of my low rep.

Comment: All right, well don't lose hope and please keep contributing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It turned out to be a sync error for some contacts with malformed birthday field created on Android which causes exchange to silently fail.**

You can debug it, by getting the Exchange [server-side logs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jasonsla/archive/2013/03/19/exchange-activesync-mailbox-logging.aspx), by going to your Exchange Webmail (Outlook Web Access, OWA):

1. Login in to webmail.yourdomain.com
2. go to: Options -> All options -> Phone
3. mark your current device and click -> "Start Logging"
4. Start sync on the phone
5. in webmail click "Stop Logging" and look at the new mail create in your inbox

In the log I got three of these errors:

`X-MS-ASError: Message = The 'Contacts::Birthday' element is invalid - The value '1979-11-24' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:dateTime' - The string '1979-11-24' is not a valid XsdDateTime value.; Severity = Error`

**... which causes the whole sync and all subsequent contact syncing to silently do nothing.** I had to remove the birthday field from these contacts on Android.

I hope this helps someone!

Here is some more information on the various date formats created on Android devices: http://dmfs.org/carddav/?date_format

Comment: The links are dead. For "server-side logs" these might help:
* https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/mobile-devices/issues-for-mobile-devices
* https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX228077